# How to make a simple text preparation program more elegant?

Tags: python, performance, python-re, codec, readlines

I'm pretty new to Python, no formal training, and I think I'm not very good at making programs that are simple, elegant, efficient, or thinking about the structure in a logical way.

I'm putting an example here to see what kind of advice people may be able to offer.
I've used mostly copy and pasting, with much trial and error, to make a few programs that prepare a text document for processing. In this one, I want to get rid of things like timestamps and identifying information, leaving only the text of the messages that have been extracted.

It does what I want but seems clunky and I'm sure there are other ways to do the same thing and have it be more flexible (maybe with pandas?)

Thank you in advance!

PS the text of the starting document is at the end, it's a small test version only 6 lines.

```
import re, codecs

def regex(txt):
    txt = re.sub(r'(LOC\d\d\d\d: )', "", txt)
    txt = re.sub(r'(\d\d:\d\d - )', "", txt)
    txt = re.sub(r'(\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d, )', "", txt)
    return(txt)

stopwords=["Alexandra", "Gomez:"]
fj="(fichier joint)\r\n"
app="Votre code de sécurité"
mo="<Médias omis>"

corpus=[]

file="Lat_small.txt"
with codecs.open(file, 'r', 'utf8') as f:
    text=f.readlines()

    with codecs.open("Latinos_clean.txt", 'w', 'utf8') as l:
        for line in text:
            line=regex(line)
            if not line.endswith(fj) and not line.startswith(app) and not line.startswith(mo):
                corpus.append(line)

        for lines in corpus:
            lines =lines.split()
            words=[]
            for word in lines:
                if word not in stopwords:
                    words.append(word)

            final=' '.join(words)
            l.write(final+"\n")
```

text of Lat_small.txt:

```
19/04/2022, 20:49 - Alexandra Gomez: Gracias por sus mensajes :)
19/04/2022, 21:45 - LOC0006: ‎PTT-20220419-WA0037.opus (fichier joint)
19/04/2022, 21:47 - LOC0007: Publicado también en un grupo que se llama wanted en facebook
19/04/2022, 21:51 - LOC0008: Listo paisano, éxitos!
19/04/2022, 21:51 - LOC0008: <Médias omis>
24/04/2022, 19:42 - Votre code de sécurité avec LOC0082 a changé. Appuyez pour en savoir plus.
```

Comment: Kat, this belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). StackOverflow is for specific questions. I'll respond if you post it there.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Before you post at [codereview.se], be sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *is for*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.